# When to say “to be” and “to have been”?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

In situations like this one (neither I know if this sentence is gramatically correct, nor I know who is Merkel): 
"In her campaigning, Ms Merkel never pretended to be a dissident or an oposition activist in the GDR."
Are there any other similar forms like maybe "to had been"(idk if it even exists)?

Comment: In the context of ***to pretend to [verb]*** *(He pretends **to know**, She pretended **to listen**)*, the *[**verb**]* element must always be an *infinitive* (only the "primary" verb ***pretend*** is conjugated for tense / number). So there's no such sequence as *pretend **to had been*** in English. Chancellor Angela Merkel has been in charge of Germany (and effectively, the EU) for many years now.

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

> In her campaigning, Ms Merkel never pretended to have been a dissident
>   or an opposition activist in the GDR.

It would mean that she never pretended (in the then present) to have been something in the past (i.e. prior to the then present).